# doctrine arraycollection filter performance

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-query

I need filter DoctrineCollection but the collection is very big. My question refers to performance in big collections. for example:

```
 $collections->filter(function($obj){
    if($obj->getAttr() == X){
        return $obj;
    }
 });
```

if the $collections contains, for example, one million of records then the performance is degraded. What the solution for filter big collections ?

Answer (score 0):

make a query should be great solutions but if you have one million of records you should implement a pagination too